# How can i put this object in material table in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently i am working on a project where I am required to gather data from an aws aurora database and display it on a table. I am planning on using a material table and I cannot figure out how to place the data in the table.

**Here is the component  that gathers asks for the data:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CandidateService} from '../../shared/candidate.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-list',
  templateUrl: './candidate-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate-list.component.css']
})
export class CandidateListComponent implements OnInit {

  candidateRecordAvailabe: boolean = false;
  tableData: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayColumns: string[] = ['first_name'];
  constructor(private candidateService: CandidateService) { }

  //Variables for the component


  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchCandidateRecords();
    this.putCandidateRecords();
  }  

  /* fetch candidates from the candidates service and retrying till aws aurora server starts */
   async fetchCandidateRecords(){
    //check if candidate list already exists in the candidate.service
    if(this.candidateService.candidateRecords == null) {
      await this.candidateService.fetchAllCandidates().subscribe(
        (recordData: []) => {  
          console.log(typeof(recordData));
          console.log(recordData);
          this.candidateService.candidateRecords = recordData;
          this.candidateRecordAvailabe = true;
          this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(this.candidateService.candidateRecords);
        }, 
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      this.candidateRecordAvailabe = true;
      this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(this.candidateService.candidateRecords);
    }
  }

  putCandidateRecords(){
    this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(this.candidateService.candidateRecords);
  }

}
```

**Below is the service function that subscribes to the HTTP request and collects the data**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { retryAfterDelay } from './custom.delay';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandidateService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  candidateRecords: [] = null;   // Stores the records of all the candidates from fetch candidates
  delayDuration: number = 20000;  //20 seconds of delay

  fetchAllCandidates(): Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.get('url--here---')
      .pipe(
       retryAfterDelay(this.delayDuration),
       catchError(errorResponse => {
         return throwError(errorResponse);
       }
      )
      );
  } 

}
```

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z0" *ngIf="candidateRecordAvailabe">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="tableData">
        <mat-header-cell>first_name</mat-header-cell>   
        <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.first_name|json}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>

<div class="container h-100" *ngIf="!candidateRecordAvailabe">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto uploader-status ">
                <mat-spinner strokeWidth="25" [diameter]="100" title="Server Starting" ></mat-spinner>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Now, here is the error I am facing. The below images also consist of the type of data I am receiving***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you also post your HTML?  `columDef` is something from the HTML so I'm fairly sure your error might be located in the HTML.

Comment: i have edit the question and added the HTML sir !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight mistake in your code as per documentation in your html the `ng-container` part will be like this as follows:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayColumns; index as i">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    {{ column=='first_name' ? 'First Name' : '' }}
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.first_name | json }}</td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
```

The problem with your part was you were not iterating the `displayColumns` to extract each column and put in `matColumnDef`.

I hope this [documentation](https://stackblitz.com/angular/emdqrdjmbkl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) in Angular material will help you.

Comment: I did changes with my original code based on your suggestion and it works. But the error I am facing now is that I cant load the data into the table

Comment: @joel can you create a dummy Stackblitz example based on your logic ? Else it will be hard to understand

Comment: Thank you avishek. But i have solved the issue. Inorder to load the data into the table. I had to load it as a table source.
this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(this.candidateService.candidateRecords);

But as we can see in the screenshot that the output arrays were enclosed in another object named record.
So I just change the above piece of code to

this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records);

Comment: great . Glad to see this helped you